# Block bulk user accounts

Tags: powershell, office365

Any way to block user account in Office365 by EmployeeID instead of UPN?

This is the script I've tried, but it can only block by UPN:

```
Import-Csv 'C:\BlockedUsers.csv' | ForEach-Object {
$upn = $_."UserPrincipalName"
Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $upn -BlockCredential $true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your csv file contains a column called `EmployeeId`, you can use that to get the UserPrincipalName property using the `Get-AdUser` cmdlet:

```
Import-Csv 'C:\BlockedUsers.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    $user = Get-ADUser -Properties EmployeeID -Filter "EmployeeID -eq $($_.EmployeeID)"
    if ($user) {
        $upn = $user.UserPrincipleName
        Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $upn -BlockCredential $true
    }
}
```

---

**Edit**

Judging by your comment, it seems the `EmployeeID` property is not always unique in your organization.

In that case, the below code should be able to handle that

```
Import-Csv 'C:\BlockedUsers.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    $user = Get-ADUser -Properties EmployeeID -Filter "EmployeeID -eq $($_.EmployeeID)"
    if ($user) {
        foreach ($usr in $user) {
            Write-Host "Blocking user $($usr.Name)"
            $upn = $usr.UserPrincipleName
            Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $upn -BlockCredential $true
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "User with EmployeeID $($_.EmployeeID) not found"
    }
}
```

P.S. If your CSV can contain empty values for the `EmployeeID` column, change the first line into

```
Import-Csv 'C:\BlockedUsers.csv' | Where-Object {$_.EmployeeID -match '\S'} | ForEach-Object {
```

to get rid of empty or whitespace-only values.

---

**Edit**

If you are sure your CSV contains a column `EmployeeId` and you are not mistaking that with AD property `EmployeeNumber`, then perhaps this might work for you.
It uses `Get-ADUser` to get a collection of user objects that actually **have** something in their EmployeeId attribute and refines that by comparing to the ones you have read from the CSV using `Where-Object`.

Both `EmployeeId` and `EmployeeNUmber` are AD properties of type `String`. You can look that up [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/adschema/attributes-all)

```
# first read the CSV into an array containing only the values from the 'EmployeeID' column
$blockedUserIds = Import-Csv 'C:\BlockedUsers.csv' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty EmployeeId -Unique

# next get an array of user objects that have something in the EmployeeID attribute and only
# leave the users where the attribute can be matched to a value captured in the CSV array above
# use the '@(..)' syntax to force the result to be an array, even if only one item is found
$usersToBlock = @(Get-ADUser -Properties EmployeeID, Name, UserPrincipalName -Filter "EmployeeID -like '*'" | 
                  Where-Object { $blockedUserIds -contains $_.EmployeeID })

# you can also use the '-LDAPFilter' parameter
# $usersToBlock = @(Get-ADUser -Properties EmployeeID, Name, UserPrincipalName  -LDAPFilter "(employeeID=*)" | 
#                   Where-Object { $blockedUserIds -contains $_.EmployeeID })

# you now should have an array of user objects that need to be blocked
if ($usersToBlock.Count) {
    Write-Host "Blocking $($usersToBlock.Count) users.." -ForegroundColor Green
    $usersToBlock | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host "Blocking user $($_.Name)"
        Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $($_.UserPrincipleName) -BlockCredential $true
    }
}
else {
    Write-Warning "No users found with an EmployeeId property that matches any of the values in BlockedUsers.csv"
}
```

Comment: thank you, so i have a column called EmployeeID, i tried the script you provided and this is the error i got: Set-MsolUser : Cannot convert 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'UserPrincipalName'. Specified method is not 
supported.
At line:5 char:41
+         Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $upn -BlockCredential $true

Comment: @LarryDavid It looks like multiple users can have the same EmployeeID in your organization. I have edited my answer to handle that.

Comment: Odd, @theo even after the updated change: I'm still getting Set-MsolUser : Cannot convert 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'UserPrincipalName'. Specified method is not 
supported.

Comment: @LarryDavid Are you perhaps altering this code inside a loaded module? If that is the case, changes in the module are not reflected unless you exit PowerShell, use `Import-Module ... -Force` or even `Remove-Module ...; Import-Module ...`

Comment: i know when i connect to office365, this is how i connect office 365 $powerUser = 'xxxxxx@xxxxxxxx'

$powerPass = 'xxxxxxx'

$password = ConvertTo-SecureString $powerPass -AsPlainText -Force

$adminCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $powerUser,$password

Import-Module MSOnline

Connect-MsolService -Credential $adminCredential

$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $adminCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection

Comment: then on seperate tab i run your script all in powershell ise

Comment: @LarryDavid I have updated the answer, because I realized the `EmployeeID` property is not in the default set of properties PowerShell returns on `Get-ADUser`. I have added `-Properties EmployeeID` to the cmdlet. I'm sorry I cannot try this myself right now.

Comment: it's fine, i've gotten the same error message after updates. i'll work on this some more and see if i can get something to work out!

Comment: still no dice on getting this to work, any ideas? not sure if u testing on  your end by any chance

Comment: @LarryDavid I think the main problem is _"then on seperate tab i run your script all in powershell ise"_, because AFAIK, the secondary tab opens a **new PS instance** and script tabs are not shared between the PowerShell tabs. Ergo: run both the script to connect to Office365 and this script within the same tab. If it is any help to you, I have added code to my answer to tackle this in an alternative way.

Comment: @LarryDavid P.S. If you want to check if different users in your environment have duplicate EmployeeId attributes, there is a script [Find Active Directory duplicated attributes](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Find-Active-Directory-c8789b42) you can download for that.